# Linux cut string

Tags: linux, string, bash, cut

In Linux (Cento OS) I have a file that contains a set of additional information that I want  to removed. I want to generate a new file with all characters until to the first `|`.

The file has the following information:

```
ALFA12345|7890
Beta0-XPTO-2|30452|90 385|29
ZETA2334423 435; 2|2|90dd5|dddd29|dqe3
```

The output expected will be:

```
ALFA12345
Beta0 XPTO-2
ZETA2334423 435; 2
```

That is removed all characters after the character `|` (inclusive).

Any suggestion for a script that reads  `File1` and generates `File2` with this specific requirement?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
cut -d'|' -f1 oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

And, to round out the "big 3", here's the `awk` version:

```
awk -F\| '{print $1}' in.dat
```

Comment: Big 3.. what about `grep`? (+1)

Comment: @sudo_O Yeah, ok, snarkiness failure... We could probably toss in the `perl`, `python`, `lua`, etc. too... "Super 7" maybe? "Enlightened 11"?

Comment: Haha why stop there! I would say Super 6 `cut,awk,sed,grep,perl,vi/emacs`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple sed script.

```
sed 's/^\([^|]*\).*/\1/g' in.dat 
ALFA12345
Beta0-XPTO-2
ZETA2334423 435; 2
```

Redirect to a file to capture the output.

```
sed 's/^\([^|]*\).*/\1/g' in.dat > out.dat
```

Comment: removing anything that starts with | would make the expression much simpler

Comment: Agree with qdii. `s/|.*//'`

Comment: This definitely is the wrong approach. You match the whole line but yet use the `g` flag and capture groups are overkill. The logic should be replace everything from `|` with nothing, not replace the whole line with the first bit of the line I captured. @Kevin's comment contains the correct `sed` solution.

Answer (score 0):

And with `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '^[^|]*' file1
ALFA12345
Beta0-XPTO-2
ZETA2334423 435; 2

$ grep -o '^[^|]*' file1 > file2
```